# Customize CSS Styles on Iframe in React

Tags: css, reactjs, iframe, styled-components

I need to style the css of an iframe of a website. How do you customize it like hiding the navigation menu? I'm using styled-components and react.

Check my codesandbox here
[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-styled-components-iframe-forked-udmid?file=/src/Main.js)

```
const FormContainer = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: scroll;

  & iframe {
    & #page-header-container {
      display: none !important;
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the `iframe` styles from a parent element. It's not allowed due to security concerns by the browsers.